# 2 (311/313)test cases failing for this leetcode problem(3sum)

Tags: javascript

For this [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/)

My 2 test cases are failing and saying maximum time limit exceeded
I attempted this with this:

```
var threeSum = function(nums) {
    var triplets = [];
    nums.sort();
    var size = nums.length;
    for(var i = 0 ;i<nums.length;i++) {

    for(var j = i+1; j<nums.length; j++) {
        sum = nums[i]+ nums[j];
        wanted = 0 - sum;
        if(nums.indexOf(wanted,j+1)>-1) {
        index = nums.indexOf(wanted,j); 
        var pushed = [nums[i],nums[j],nums[index]];
        pushed.sort();

        var same = false;
        if(triplets.length>0){
        for(var k =0 ; k<triplets.length;k++){

        if(triplets[k][0] === pushed[0]  &&  triplets[k][1] === pushed[1]) {
            same = true;
        }
        }
        if(same ===false) {
            triplets.push(pushed);
        }
    }
        if(triplets.length===0) {
            triplets.push(pushed);
        }

        }
    }
    nums.splice(i,1);
    i--;


}

    return (triplets);

};
```

But only 311/313 are passing
Can anybody tell me why this is failing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see multiple improvements on your algorithm. At the beginning you are sorting the array but not making use of it , even if you remove the sorting this algorithm will work as is.Also using the indexOf multiple times in each iteration can be costly for larger inputs.

I think you can solve this problem efficiently by sorting first and using two pointers method than your current approach.